# Why does the HttpGet method get invoked again when the form is submitted with POST verb?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

### Controller:

```
// other usings are removed for the sake of brevity
using MvcMovie.Models;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        private MoviewDBContext db = new MoviewDBContext();

        public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
        {
            var movies = db.Movies.Select(x => x);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                movies = movies.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(searchString));

            return View(movies);
        }

    }
}
```

### View:

```
// SearhcIndex.cshtml

@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Title: @Html.TextBox("searchString")
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

The first time I visit `localhost/Movies/SearchIndex`, the `HttpGet SearchIndex` will be invoked and it populates the model for the corresponding view. Once the view is rendered on the browser, I enter a word to filter out the list and followed by pressing the submit button `Filter`.

My question is:

Clicking the `Filter`, in my opinion, will submit the form with POST verb. But why does the `HttpGet SearchIndex` get invoked **again**? I have no `HttpPost SearchIndex` implemented yet (for sure).

Note: I am a newbie, please don't downvote without giving a reason from which I can learn. I am reading this tutorial ["Examining the Edit Methods and Edit View"](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view).

Comment: Take a look at the params for `Html.BeginForm()` because GET is the default, you'll want something like `Html.BeginForm("Movies", "SearchIndex", FormMethod.Post)`.

Comment: @truemedia: Do you mean `Html.BeginForm()` will be submitted with GET verb if I press the `Filter` button?

Comment: @truemedia: Then I have misunderstood the concept of GET and POST. I thought pressing button will submit the form with POST verb.

Comment: Form is indeed submitted as POST in your example - to check that, use `var method = Request.HttpMethod;` in your controller action

Comment: The default method is POST and not GET

Comment: @Corneliu and andreister : You are correct!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does this because you haven't specified that it should only handle get requests, so by default it will handle both. If you were to add the `HttpGet` attribute it would have the behavior that you are expecting

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
    {
        var movies = db.Movies.Select(x => x);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            movies = movies.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(searchString));

        return View(movies);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString, string someOtherParam)
    {
        var movies = db.Movies.Select(x => x);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            movies = movies.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(searchString));
        //do something different than your get...
        return View(movies);
    }
```

Note that I included another method here for handling the Post, as surely you still want to. As mentioned in a comment, if this still fails, explicity specify POST in your form, although, I've never had to do that to make this work and I do not expect you will need it here.

Also note that your post method will either need a different name, or it will need different parameters than your get (so that .net can differentiate them)

Since you mention being a newbie, here is the MVC tutorial that I prefer and have new devs read when starting MVC:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store

If you have not done so, you should check it out!

**Update**:

Based on your comment, here is what they're telling you at the link you provided. When a request is routed to your controller, MVC will pick the very first Action Method that exactly matches the request. If you do not apply `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]` then that Action Method will accept both. So let's say that you browse to /mysite/Movies/SearchIndex. Using MY EXAMPLE ABOVE, this is a GET request, so MVC sees that you have SearchIndex marked with [HttpGet] and that is what it will use.

Now let's say you remove the `[HttpGet]` but leave `[HttpPost]` on the other (as in the example from the article you provided). If you browse to /mysite/Movies/SearchIndex MVC sees the SearchIndex() marked with HTTPPost and says, Can't use that one! Then it sees SearchIndex() with no attributes (meaning it accepts both Post and Get) and uses it.

Similarly if you cause a /mysite/Movies/SearchIndex with a POST request, MVC sees that you have a SearchIndex() marked with `[HttpPost]` so it uses that one as it is an exact match.

The point that the article is failing to get across right there, is that the default behavior for a method is to accept both GET and POST. What the article is actually saying at that point, is given that specific scenario, where one is marked with `[HttpPost]` and the other not marked at all, the default behavior will cause the unmarked Action Method to be used.

I apologize if this is confusing, I rewrote this several times but it's slightly complex to explain.

Comment: Are you sure that an action method without an attribute will handle both POST and GET? In my understanding, without attribute represents GET by default.

Comment: I am 100% certain. I believe the tutorial that I linked mentions this, but it's been a while since I read it. MVC does this so that you are not required to specify seperate methods for Get and Post as in many instances, you don't need this behavior.

Comment: I have read [this link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view), the important quote is [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/52AJg.png). What do you think?

Comment: I updated with a rather lengthy explanation. Past this we'll need to converse via chat if it is not clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Because u dont have the POST method and GET invokes by default. Add this after your SearchIndexaction

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
        {
          do post stuff here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right the form will be sent using POST method. And it is sent to your SearchIndex action with POST verb. To check that please decorate your SearchIndex action with HttpGet Attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
    {
        var movies = db.Movies.Select(x => x);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            movies = movies.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(searchString));

        return View(movies);
    }
```

After adding the verb filder, you will get an error when trying to POST to it.